# Сравнение времени в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Нужно вывести занятия, которые начинаются раньше 12 часов.

Разумеется, сразу попробовал `WHERE date < 12:00:00` - не получилось.

Попробовал `WHERE date < 120000`, так у нас время - целочисленный тип данных, а не строка, - и всё равно не получается.

Comment: а в базе время точно хранится как 120000 ? Может быть там таймстемп строка?

Comment: Уточните тип колонки `date` и приведите пример выборки `select * from you_table_name limit 1;`

Comment: возможно в поле храниться метка времени UNIX - количество секунд, прошедших с начала эпохи Unix (1 января 1970 00:00:00 GMT) до текущего времени. И нужно писать не 120000 а количество секундю

Answer (score 0):

Сделай вот такой запрос и покажи здесь что тебе вернуло. Тогда все вопросы очень быстро пропадут

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
```

возможно в поле храниться метка времени UNIX - количество секунд, прошедших с начала эпохи Unix (1 января 1970 00:00:00 GMT) до текущего времени. И нужно писать не 120000 а количество секунд.

Возможно нужно так проверять

```
WHERE columname < '12:00:00'
```

То есть сравнивать со строкой

Comment: Удивительно, но почему-то сегодня все работает. И 120000 и '12:00:00'. Походу, не заметил ошибку какую-то. Но компилятор говорил что все нормально. Спасибо за внимание и прошу прощения за собственную глупость.

P.S  Спасибо за команду INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Узнал много нового)